# Creating Data Extension using Apex (WSDL2Apex)

Tags: apex, marketing-cloud, soap-api, dataextensions, wsdl2apex

I am really struggling to write an Apex Class to create a Data Extension in Marketing Cloud. I have parsed the WSDL and generated the Apex class.
From here, not able to write my class to create the Data Extension.
Which class from WSDL should I use ? Is it CreateRequest_element?

Any sample code will really help. Thanks!

Comment: Whats the WSDL that got parsed ?

Comment: It's the standard ExactTarget WSDL

Comment: whats the url you downloaded from ?

Comment: https://webservice.s6.exacttarget.com/etframework.wsdl

Comment: Did you resolve the XSD references .If you can share the final modified WSDL i can try helping here

Comment: Yes I resolved all the  XSD references .. it's a gigantic WSDL.. I can send on your personal email Id if that's okay

Comment: Have you tried [my alternative version of WSDL2Apex](http://www.fishofprey.com/2014/11/dreamforce-2014-presentation-improved.html)?

Comment: Hi Daniel, I have been able to Generate the Apex classes in Salesforce successfully. Where I am struggling is from here how do I use this Apex class to interact with ExactTarget

Answer (score 4):

The method to target is below

```
public exacttargetComWsdlPartnerapi.CreateResponse_element Create(exacttargetComWsdlPartnerapi.CreateOptions Options,exacttargetComWsdlPartnerapi.APIObject[] Objects) {
        exacttargetComWsdlPartnerapi.CreateRequest_element request_x = new exacttargetComWsdlPartnerapi.CreateRequest_element();
        request_x.Options = Options;
        request_x.Objects = Objects;
        exacttargetComWsdlPartnerapi.CreateResponse_element response_x;
        Map<String, exacttargetComWsdlPartnerapi.CreateResponse_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, exacttargetComWsdlPartnerapi.CreateResponse_element>();
        response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
        WebServiceCallout.invoke(
          this,
          request_x,
          response_map_x,
          new String[]{endpoint_x,
          'Create',
          'http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI',
          'CreateRequest',
          'http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI',
          'CreateResponse',
          'exacttargetComWsdlPartnerapi.CreateResponse_element'}
        );
        response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
        return response_x;
    }
```

and a sample request XML for Data extension creation looks like below

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Header>
    <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">6Olmsi1lENynJSOqox1j6hGm</fueloauth>
</Header>
<Body>
    <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
        <Options>
            <SaveOptions/>
        </Options>
        <Objects xsi:type="DataExtension">
            <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
            <CustomerKey>02_2010-02-26-08_42_30_762_851628611</CustomerKey>
            <Name>02_2010-02-26-08_42_30_762_851628611</Name>
            <Description>02_2010-02-26-08_42_30_762_851628611</Description>
            <IsSendable>true</IsSendable>
            <IsTestable>false</IsTestable>
            <DataRetentionPeriodLength>360</DataRetentionPeriodLength>
            <DataRetentionPeriod>Days</DataRetentionPeriod>
            <RowBasedRetention>false</RowBasedRetention>
            <ResetRetentionPeriodOnImport>true</ResetRetentionPeriodOnImport>
            <DeleteAtEndOfRetentionPeriod>false</DeleteAtEndOfRetentionPeriod>
            <Fields>
                <Field>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <Name>D_Body</Name>
                    <Description>D_Body</Description>
                    <IsNillable>false</IsNillable>
                    <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
                    <FieldType>Text</FieldType>
                    <DefaultValue/>
                </Field>
                <Field>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <Name>D_F1</Name>
                    <Description>D_F1</Description>
                    <MaxLength>100</MaxLength>
                    <IsNillable>false</IsNillable>
                    <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
                    <FieldType>Text</FieldType>
                    <DefaultValue/>
                </Field>
                <Field>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <Name>D_F2</Name>
                    <Description>D_F2</Description>
                    <MaxLength>100</MaxLength>
                    <IsNillable>false</IsNillable>
                    <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
                    <FieldType>Text</FieldType>
                    <DefaultValue/>
                </Field>
                <Field>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <Name>D_F3</Name>
                    <Description>D_F3</Description>
                    <MaxLength>100</MaxLength>
                    <IsNillable>false</IsNillable>
                    <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
                    <FieldType>Text</FieldType>
                    <DefaultValue/>
                </Field>
                <Field>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <Name>D_F4</Name>
                    <Description>D_F4</Description>
                    <MaxLength>100</MaxLength>
                    <IsNillable>false</IsNillable>
                    <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
                    <FieldType>Text</FieldType>
                    <DefaultValue/>
                </Field>
                <Field>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <Name>D_F5</Name>
                    <Description>D_F5</Description>
                    <MaxLength>100</MaxLength>
                    <IsNillable>false</IsNillable>
                    <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
                    <FieldType>Text</FieldType>
                    <DefaultValue/>
                </Field>
                <Field>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <Name>D_From Email</Name>
                    <Description>D_From Email</Description>
                    <MaxLength>320</MaxLength>
                    <IsNillable>false</IsNillable>
                    <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
                    <FieldType>Text</FieldType>
                    <DefaultValue/>
                </Field>
                <Field>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <Name>D_From Name</Name>
                    <Description>D_From Name</Description>
                    <MaxLength>1024</MaxLength>
                    <IsNillable>false</IsNillable>
                    <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
                    <FieldType>Text</FieldType>
                    <DefaultValue/>
                </Field>
                <Field>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <Name>D_Subject</Name>
                    <Description>D_Subject</Description>
                    <MaxLength>1024</MaxLength>
                    <IsNillable>false</IsNillable>
                    <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
                    <FieldType>Text</FieldType>
                    <DefaultValue/>
                </Field>
                <Field>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <Name>Email Address</Name>
                    <Description>Email Address</Description>
                    <MaxLength>100</MaxLength>
                    <IsNillable>false</IsNillable>
                    <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
                    <FieldType>EmailAddress</FieldType>
                </Field>
                <Field>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <Name>Subscriber Key</Name>
                    <Description>Subscriber Key</Description>
                    <MaxLength>100</MaxLength>
                    <IsNillable>false</IsNillable>
                    <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
                    <FieldType>Text</FieldType>
                    <DefaultValue/>
                </Field>
                <Field>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <Name>D_FileAttachmentFileName1</Name>
                    <Description>D_FileAttachmentFileName1</Description>
                    <MaxLength>1024</MaxLength>
                    <IsNillable>false</IsNillable>
                    <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
                    <FieldType>Text</FieldType>
                    <DefaultValue/>
                </Field>
                <Field>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <Name>D_FileAttachmentPhysicalFile1</Name>
                    <Description>D_FileAttachmentPhysicalFile1</Description>
                    <MaxLength>1024</MaxLength>
                    <IsNillable>false</IsNillable>
                    <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
                    <FieldType>Text</FieldType>
                    <DefaultValue/>
                </Field>
                <Field>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <Name>D_FileAttachmentFileName2</Name>
                    <Description>D_FileAttachmentFileName2</Description>
                    <MaxLength>1024</MaxLength>
                    <IsNillable>false</IsNillable>
                    <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
                    <FieldType>Text</FieldType>
                    <DefaultValue/>
                </Field>
                <Field>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <Name>D_FileAttachmentPhysicalFile2</Name>
                    <Description>D_FileAttachmentPhysicalFile2</Description>
                    <MaxLength>1024</MaxLength>
                    <IsNillable>false</IsNillable>
                    <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
                    <FieldType>Text</FieldType>
                    <DefaultValue/>
                </Field>
                <Field>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <Name>D_FileAttachmentFileName3</Name>
                    <Description>D_FileAttachmentFileName3</Description>
                    <MaxLength>1024</MaxLength>
                    <IsNillable>false</IsNillable>
                    <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
                    <FieldType>Text</FieldType>
                    <DefaultValue/>
                </Field>
                <Field>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <Name>D_FileAttachmentPhysicalFile3</Name>
                    <Description>D_FileAttachmentPhysicalFile3</Description>
                    <MaxLength>1024</MaxLength>
                    <IsNillable>false</IsNillable>
                    <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
                    <FieldType>Text</FieldType>
                    <DefaultValue/>
                </Field>
                <Field>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <Name>D_FileAttachmentFileName4</Name>
                    <Description>D_FileAttachmentFileName4</Description>
                    <MaxLength>1024</MaxLength>
                    <IsNillable>false</IsNillable>
                    <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
                    <FieldType>Text</FieldType>
                    <DefaultValue/>
                </Field>
                <Field>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <Name>D_FileAttachmentPhysicalFile4</Name>
                    <Description>D_FileAttachmentPhysicalFile4</Description>
                    <MaxLength>1024</MaxLength>
                    <IsNillable>false</IsNillable>
                    <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
                    <FieldType>Text</FieldType>
                    <DefaultValue/>
                </Field>
                <Field>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <Name>D_FileAttachmentFileName5</Name>
                    <Description>D_FileAttachmentFileName5</Description>
                    <MaxLength>1024</MaxLength>
                    <IsNillable>false</IsNillable>
                    <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
                    <FieldType>Text</FieldType>
                    <DefaultValue/>
                </Field>
                <Field>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <Name>D_FileAttachmentPhysicalFile5</Name>
                    <Description>D_FileAttachmentPhysicalFile5</Description>
                    <MaxLength>1024</MaxLength>
                    <IsNillable>false</IsNillable>
                    <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
                    <FieldType>Text</FieldType>
                    <DefaultValue/>
                </Field>
                <Field>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <Name>D_URLAttachmentURL1</Name>
                    <Description>D_URLAttachmentURL1</Description>
                    <MaxLength>1024</MaxLength>
                    <IsNillable>false</IsNillable>
                    <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
                    <FieldType>Text</FieldType>
                    <DefaultValue/>
                </Field>
                <Field>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <Name>D_URLAttachmentFileName1</Name>
                    <Description>D_URLAttachmentFileName1</Description>
                    <MaxLength>1024</MaxLength>
                    <IsNillable>false</IsNillable>
                    <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
                    <FieldType>Text</FieldType>
                    <DefaultValue/>
                </Field>
                <Field>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <Name>D_URLAttachmentURL2</Name>
                    <Description>D_URLAttachmentURL2</Description>
                    <MaxLength>1024</MaxLength>
                    <IsNillable>false</IsNillable>
                    <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
                    <FieldType>Text</FieldType>
                    <DefaultValue/>
                </Field>
                <Field>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <Name>D_URLAttachmentFileName2</Name>
                    <Description>D_URLAttachmentFileName2</Description>
                    <MaxLength>1024</MaxLength>
                    <IsNillable>false</IsNillable>
                    <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
                    <FieldType>Text</FieldType>
                    <DefaultValue/>
                </Field>
                <Field>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <Name>D_URLAttachmentURL3</Name>
                    <Description>D_URLAttachmentURL3</Description>
                    <MaxLength>1024</MaxLength>
                    <IsNillable>false</IsNillable>
                    <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
                    <FieldType>Text</FieldType>
                    <DefaultValue/>
                </Field>
                <Field>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <Name>D_URLAttachmentFileName3</Name>
                    <Description>D_URLAttachmentFileName3</Description>
                    <MaxLength>1024</MaxLength>
                    <IsNillable>false</IsNillable>
                    <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
                    <FieldType>Text</FieldType>
                    <DefaultValue/>
                </Field>
                <Field>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <Name>D_URLAttachmentURL4</Name>
                    <Description>D_URLAttachmentURL4</Description>
                    <MaxLength>1024</MaxLength>
                    <IsNillable>false</IsNillable>
                    <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
                    <FieldType>Text</FieldType>
                    <DefaultValue/>
                </Field>
                <Field>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <Name>D_URLAttachmentFileName4</Name>
                    <Description>D_URLAttachmentFileName4</Description>
                    <MaxLength>1024</MaxLength>
                    <IsNillable>false</IsNillable>
                    <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
                    <FieldType>Text</FieldType>
                    <DefaultValue/>
                </Field>
                <Field>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <Name>D_URLAttachmentURL5</Name>
                    <Description>D_URLAttachmentURL5</Description>
                    <MaxLength>1024</MaxLength>
                    <IsNillable>false</IsNillable>
                    <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
                    <FieldType>Text</FieldType>
                    <DefaultValue/>
                </Field>
                <Field>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <Name>D_URLAttachmentFileName5</Name>
                    <Description>D_URLAttachmentFileName5</Description>
                    <MaxLength>1024</MaxLength>
                    <IsNillable>false</IsNillable>
                    <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
                    <FieldType>Text</FieldType>
                    <DefaultValue/>
                </Field>
            </Fields>
            <SendableDataExtensionField>
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                <Name>Email Address</Name>
            </SendableDataExtensionField>
            <SendableSubscriberField>
                <Name>Email Address</Name>
            </SendableSubscriberField>
        </Objects>
    </CreateRequest>
</Body>
```

So our apex class would need to map the above XML using the generated class like below

The apex stub method would look like below

```
   exacttargetComWsdlPartnerapi partnerAPI = new    exacttargetComWsdlPartnerapi();

    exacttargetComWsdlPartnerapi.APIProperty[] propertiesarray = new   exacttargetComWsdlPartnerapi.APIProperty[]();

    exacttargetComWsdlPartnerapi.SaveOption saveOption = new    exacttargetComWsdlPartnerapi.SaveOption();
    list<exacttargetComWsdlPartnerapi.SaveOption> lstsaveOptions = new      list<exacttargetComWsdlPartnerapi.SaveOption> ();
      exacttargetComWsdlPartnerapi.SaveOptions_element sOption = new   exacttargetComWsdlPartnerapi.SaveOptions_element();
     sOption.SaveOption = lstsaveOptions.add(saveOption);

    exacttargetComWsdlPartnerapi.Options options = new    exacttargetComWsdlPartnerapi.Options();
    options.SaveOptions = sOption;


     exacttargetComWsdlPartnerapi.CreateOptions createoptions = new      exacttargetComWsdlPartnerapi.CreateOptions();
    createoptions.options = options;

    exacttargetComWsdlPartnerapi.APIProperty[] objects = new    exacttargetComWsdlPartnerapi.APIProperty[]();



   partnerAPI.Create(containerId,objects);
```

This is just a sample while forming full apex and stub methods will take hours .Hope this gives you a good starting point